# Why does this javascript keeps recursing

Tags: javascript, closures

I am reading Secrets of the javascript ninja listing 5.6. In the explanation, the author asks to move the variables into the global scope. Then, create another id which is box2 and call animate on box2 right after animate on box1 to show the protection that closures provide to variables. I understand that concept but the result that I got was an infinite recursion of the assert statements. I don't understand this.

Why does this happen? Why does it get into an infinite recursion loop?

The code is below.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Listing 5.6</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/assert.js"></script>
  <link href="../styles/assert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
    #box { 
      position: absolute;
      border: 3px solid blue;
      width: 200px; height: 200px;
      background-color: #6495ed; 
      font-size: 2em; 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box">ボックス</div>                               <!--#1-->
  <div id="box2">ボックス</div>                               <!--#1-->

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var elem;
    var tick;
    var timer;

    function animateIt(elementId) {

      elem = document.getElementById(elementId);              //#2
      tick = 0;                                               //#3

      timer = setInterval(function(){                         //#4
        if (tick < 100) {
          elem.style.left = elem.style.top = tick + "px";
          tick++;
        }
        else {
          clearInterval(timer);
          assert(tick == 100,                                      //#5
               "Tick accessed via a closure.");
          assert(elem,
               "Element also accessed via a closure.");
          assert(timer,
               "Timer reference also obtained via a closure." );
        }
      }, 10);

    }

    animateIt('box');                                               //#6
    animateIt('box2');                                               //#6

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
animateIt('box');                                               //#6
animateIt('box2');
```

Once the second call happens it will replace the timer value with the new value. And you lost the reference to the first timer.So when `tick` reaches `100` it will cancel only the second timer avoiding the first. You can do some thing like below instead.

```
var timer = {}, ticks = {};

function animateIt(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);              //#2
    ticks[elementId] = 0; 
    timer[elementId] = setInterval(function(elementId, element){                         //#4
        //Increase the ticks[elementId]
        //Update the element position
        //While clearing use timer[elementId]
    }, 10);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you have defined your variables in a global state, so they get change whereas you have used them in your setInterval callback function, but if you anyway want to use it like this, you should use closures:

```
function animateIt(elementId) {

    elem = document.getElementById(elementId); //#2
    tick = 0; //#3

    var callback = (function (elem, tick) {
        return function () {
            if (tick < 100) {
                elem.style.left = elem.style.top = tick + "px";
                tick++;
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer);
                assert(tick == 100, //#5
                "Tick accessed via a closure.");
                assert(elem,
                    "Element also accessed via a closure.");
                assert(timer,
                    "Timer reference also obtained via a closure.");
            }
        };
    })(elem);

    timer = setInterval(callback, 10);

}
```